# Create Read Only User in Keycloak Master Realm

Tags: keycloak

Customer wants to create a Keycloak user who can login to Keycloak admin portal and just view the list of users (belonging to any Realm) with their associated roles and status.

Is it possible to create a user with read only rights in Keycloak?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution ?